# Why is it that I can't compile (errors: Please use pom.xml to manage class directory and I can't use F5 to compile and run either)

Tags: java, visual-studio, compilation

I am currently making a java file in a folder named "C:\Users\acer\MEGA\MEGAsync Uploads\Second Year\First Semester\Data Structures and Algorithms\Genetic Algorithm" in VSCode. However, when I hit Run, an error forced me to add the parent folder "Data Structures and Algoritms\Genetic Algorithm"

[image: Error Image]

to Java source path but I can't do it anymore because I need to use pom.xml to manage source directory.

[image: Error 2]

When I hit F5, the path is different, too.

> & 'C:\Users\acer.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.23.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:57237' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '@C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_4z7lhy5oaj57rxbrd3o9wonul.argfile' 'GeneticAlgorithm'

How to fix these errors?

Comment: you need to configure java in vs-code here is the link to configure java in vs-code https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Comment: It worked 4 days before but now, it doesn't work anymore. These errors appeared.

Comment: did you configure java in VS-Code, Java developers use NetBeans, eclipse or Intellij for development. did you compile java program first?

Comment: yes. I successfully compiled the same program 4 days ago but now it won't work

Comment: is that class file located in the same folder which you did 4 days ago? recompile and try again

Comment: I did recompile again and it's located in the same folder. But when I added the folder to source path, the error to  use .pom appeared

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Win10 x64 tho i installed it in x32

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to follow to configure java in vs-code https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java.

Compiling and running a java program is very easy after JDK installation(https://www.guru99.com/install-java.html). Following are the steps:

1. Open a command prompt window and go to the directory where you saved the java program (MyFirstJavaProgram.java). Assume it's C:.
2. Type 'javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java' and press enter to compile your code. If there are no errors in your code, the command prompt will take you to the next line (Assumption: The path variable is set).
3. Now, type ' java MyFirstJavaProgram ' to run your program.
4. You will be able to see the result printed on the window.

Comment: @kenneth seems you are doing your homework, please follow the above instructions for compiling and executing java program

Comment: What section do I read in **https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java.** to configure java? There is no "Configure Java" header.

Comment: follow below steps to compile JAVA programs

Comment: I'm using Eclipse rn instead... Never understood it and I set that up almost a year ago and now it won't work.